# Trigger jQuery after scrollrevealjs shows the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So Im currenlty using scrollrevealjs to show divs as they appear in the view port. Im also using  http://w3lessons.info/2013/06/04/skill-bar-with-jquery-css3/ as to animate bar charts. Now my problem is that I want that animation to take place, once the https://scrollrevealjs.org/ shows those divs in the view port.

Please do let me know if you need a bit more explaination

Comment: https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollreveal#22-the-starting-defaults specifically `afterReveal: function (domEl) {}`.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Thanks for the  info. Worked like a charm :)